# Show IEEElabels with showlabel?

Tags: cross-referencing, ieeetran, showlabels

I'm using [IEEEtrantools](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/tools) to typeset equations (here's an excellent [tutorial](http://moser.cm.nctu.edu.tw/manuals.html#eqlatex)).

The package offers, among other things the `IEEEeqnarray` environment to typeset equations. That environment has an issue with labels, so one must use

```
\newcommand{\IEEElabel}[1]{\begingroup\addtocounter{equation}{-1}\refstepcounter{equation}\label{#1}\endgroup}
```

instead of `\label`.

The problem is to show `IEEElabel`s with `showlabel` (or some other way?).

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% math:
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools} % for advanced typesetting like multiline equations, and the likes.
\newcommand{\IEEElabel}[1]{\begingroup\addtocounter{equation}{-1}\refstepcounter{equation}\label{#1}\endgroup}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % to use unicode in the formulas -- to improve readability of sources
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}

% showlabels?
\usepackage[inline]{showlabels}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  e^{i π} + 1 = 0
  \IEEElabel{eq:test}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

**Edit**:

Here's a snippet with amsmath, mathtools. When I use them -- I get no labels, when I don't -- the labels are there.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% math:
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools} % for advanced typesetting like multiline equations, and the likes.
\usepackage{unicode-math} % to use unicode in the formulas -- to improve readability of sources
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}


% showlabels?
\usepackage[inline]{showlabels}


% define a general showlabels patch for equation numbering commands
\makeatletter
  \def\eqnnumpatch#1{
    \expandafter\let\csname SL@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
    \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{%
      \csname SL@#1\endcsname     %% produce original equation number %%
      \ifx\SL@labelname\relax
        % do nothing
      \else
        \SL@eqnlrtext{\SL@labelname}%     %% produce label annotation %%
      \fi
      \global\let\SL@labelname\relax
    }
  }
\makeatother

% patch the two macros relevant for the IEEEeqnarray environment
\eqnnumpatch{theequationdis}
\eqnnumpatch{theIEEEsubequationdis}


\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  e^{i π} + 1 & = & 0
  \label{eq:test}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

I have the same `IEEEtrantools` and `showlabel`. Here're the full two logs: [no math](http://pastebin.com/9GDxm9ff), [with math](http://pastebin.com/NAK4bjQE).

Comment: It seems that the `inline` option is failing with `IEEEeqalign`. Without it the example works.

Comment: @egreg: You right -- that's it!

Comment: This is now, finally, fixed. You may want to try showlabels 1.7b1 from http://purl.org/nxg/dist/showlabels or https://bitbucket.org/nxg/showlabels/downloads – thanks for reporting this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `showlabels` package redefines the `\label` macro to produce label annotations. However, within the redefined `\label` macro, it distinguishes between *text mode*, where the label annotation is produced directly, and *math mode*, where typesetting of the label annotation is put off until the actual equation number, i.e. (1), (2), etc., is typeset. The latter is done by also patching the `\@eqnnum` macro, which is used by LaTeX to typeset equation numbers, or alternatively `\maketag@@@`, which is defined by `amsmath` for the same purpose. The patched equation numbering macros then produce a label annotation by restoring the label name, which was stored in `\SL@labelname` by the `showlabels`-patched `\label` macro.

Unfortunately for you, `IEEEeqnarray` uses yet another set of macros to produce equation numbers, namely `\theequationdis` for regular equations and `\theIEEEsubequationdis` for subequations (which can be found out by looking into `IEEEtrantools.sty`). For this reason, label annotations won't show up out of the box. The obvious solution to your problem would be to patch these two commands in the same way as `\@eqnnum`, thus transparently integrating the `showlabels` functionality also into `IEEEeqnarray`.

If we look into `showlabels.sty`, we can see that the `\@eqnnum` macro is redefined in the following segment:

```
\let\SL@eqnnum=\@eqnnum
\def\@eqnnum{%
  \SL@eqnnum
  \ifx\SL@labelname\relax
    % do nothing
  \else
    \SL@eqnlrtext{\SL@labelname}%
  \fi
  \global\let\SL@labelname\relax
}
```

The important thing to note here is how the redefined macro checks whether `\SL@labelname` has been set, and if so passes it to `showlabel`'s `\SL@eqnlrtext` which produces the actual annotation. In the following MWE, I defined `\eqnnumpatch` which takes the csname of a macro and then patches it in the same way as shown above with `\@eqnnum` in the `showlabel` package. This macro is then used to patch the aforementioned equation numbering macros of `IEEEtrantools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage[inline]{showlabels}

\makeatletter
  %% 1) define a general showlabels patch for equation numbering commands
  \def\eqnnumpatch#1{
    \expandafter\let\csname SL@#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
    \expandafter\def\csname #1\endcsname{%
      \csname SL@#1\endcsname     %% produce original equation number %%
      \ifx\SL@labelname\relax
        % do nothing
      \else
        \SL@eqnlrtext{\SL@labelname}%     %% produce label annotation %%
      \fi
      \global\let\SL@labelname\relax
    }
  }
  %% 2) fix showlabel's definition of \SL@inlinetext
  \newif\ifSL@inline
  \ifx\SL@setlabel\SL@inlinetext\SL@inlinetrue\fi    %% `inline` set? %%
  \def\SL@inlinetext#1{%
    \ifmmode                               %% remove \ifSL@AMS switch %%
      \xdef\SL@labelname{\SL@prlabelname{#1}}%
    \else
      \SL@interlinetextright{\SL@prlabelname{#1}}%
    \fi
  }
  \ifSL@inline
    \let\SL@setlabel\SL@inlinetext %% correctly redefine \SL@setlabel %%
  \fi
\makeatother

%% 3) patch the two macros relevant for the IEEEeqnarray environment
\eqnnumpatch{theequationdis}
\eqnnumpatch{theIEEEsubequationdis}

%% 4) test it
\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
  e^{i p} + 1 = 0 \label{eq:first}\\
  E = mc^2 \IEEEyessubnumber\label{eq:second}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Everything XeLaTeX related was omitted for the sake of brevity.

#### edit:

This of course also works when using the `\IEEElabel` macro as defined in your question instead of `\label`. However, I wasn't able to reproduce your numbering issue, and as you didn't specify the exact problem with the `equation` counter and it appears to be unrelated to the actual `IEEEtrantools`+`showlabels` issue, I chose not to include it in the answer. Perhaps you should make sure that your version of `IEEEtrantools` is up to date.

#### edit:

My original answer did not work with `showlabel`'s `inline` option. This is due to the fact that the `\SL@inlinetext` macro is defined to do nothing in math mode if `amsmath` is used, obviously relying on the fact that the AMS environments store label names in `\df@label`. This problem has been fixed in the MWE shown above (cf. everything between comment `fix showlabel's definition of \SL@inlinetext` and `\makeatother`).

Comment: It looks like `amsmath` and/or `mathtools` break Your solution.

Comment: @Adobe could you be a bit more specific, please? When I add `\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}` to the preamble, there is no apparent change in behaviour. Make sure you include `amsmath`/`mathtools` _before_ you call `\setmathfont`. Are you using `showlabels` v1.6.5 <2009/05/29> and `IEEEtrantools` v1.3 <2012/12/27>?

Comment: Also, `amsmath` has to be included prior to `showlabels`. Otherwise the `\maketag@@@` macro will not be patched, and `showlabels` will not work in the `equation`, `align`, `split`, ... environments. This is pointed out in the `showlabels` manual.

Comment: Please see the updated question -- I've added an MWE with amsmath and mathtools -- which doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Adobe: Sorry, I forgot to check my solution with the `inline` option. I fixed the issue in my answer.

Comment: @benwilfut thanks for the analysis and draft fixes – now fixed